# CheckButton in tkinter keeps resetting instantly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm setting up the login in a larger educational desktop program, the Checkbutton is clickable but it resets instantly. It goes into an active state and then off immediately, and the check disappears afterward. How can I maintain its state/condition?

1.This is the relevant code:

```
class PageOneS(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,background="#5DADE2")
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Login", font=LFONT,foreground='white',background="#AED6F1")
        label1.pack(pady=15, padx=15)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(padx=15,ipady=10,pady=10)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Username*", font=SFONT,foreground='white',background="#F1948A")
        label2.pack(padx=575, ipady=10, pady=10,fill="x")
        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, text="",)
        entry1.pack(padx=15,ipady=10,pady=10)
        label3 = ttk.Label(self, text="Password*",font=SFONT,foreground='white',background="#F1948A")
        label3.pack(padx=575, ipady=10, pady=10,fill="x")
        entry2 = tk.Entry(self,show="*",text="", )
        entry2.pack(padx=15,ipady=10,pady=10)
        CheckVar1 = int()
        checkbox_LI = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Keep me logged in', font=SFONT,state='normal' ,foreground='white',
                                     background="#F1948A",variable = CheckVar1,
                                                             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        checkbox_LI.pack(padx=15, ipady=10, pady=10)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="login",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThreeS))
        button2.pack(padx=15,ipady=3,pady=10)

        label4 = ttk.Label(self, text="Not yet a user?", font=MFONT,foreground='white',background="#AED6F1")
        label4.pack(padx=15,ipady=10,pady=10)
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Register",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3.pack(padx=15,ipady=3,pady=10)
```

2.The programs runs well.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to set a selectcolor, e.g. add `selectcolor="F1948A"` when you create your checkbutton.

Comment: @HenryYik Tx man, it works now, have a nice day!

Comment: `CheckVar1 = int()` makes an ordinary Python integer; it's exactly the same as `CheckVar1 = 0`.  You must use `CheckVar1 = tk.IntVar()` to make a Tcl variable that can meaningfully be specified as your Checkbutton's variable.

Answer (score 0):

The foreground option is causing all the problem, remove that and you are good.